# how to solve value error in this code in python

Tags: python, valueerror

so I'm writing a code for a tipping system that on the basis of percentages calculates how much the tip added to the bill will be. I wanted to add a condition if the user wanted to give no tip

```
print("welcome to the tip calculator, hope you had a good time")
bill=input("how much was your bill\n")
tip=input("how much would you like to tip?\n No tip, 10% , 15%, 20%\n")
if tip == "No tip":
  print("Thank you for dining.") 
else: crowd= input("how many people will split the bill?\n")
new_tip= float(bill)* int(tip)/100
bill=int(bill) + int(new_tip)
pay= int(bill) / int(crowd)
print(f"Each person should pay  {pay}.")
print("Thank you.")
```

It works fine when put in any number but when I put no tip, this is the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 15, in
>
> new_tip= float(bill)* int(tip)/100
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'No tip'



Comment: You are trying to convert the string `"No tip"` to a number. What do you expect to happen? Can you think of a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is with your indentation.  When I copied your code and then indented the block of code after the "else" clause, the program ran fine.

```
print("welcome to the tip calculator, hope you had a good time")
bill=input("how much was your bill\n")
tip=input("how much would you like to tip?\n No tip, 10% , 15%, 20%\n")
if tip == "No tip":
    print("Thank you for dining.") 
else: 
    crowd= input("how many people will split the bill?\n")
    new_tip= float(bill)* int(tip)/100
    bill=int(bill) + int(new_tip)
    pay= int(bill) / int(crowd)
    print(f"Each person should pay  {pay}.")
    print("Thank you.")
```

Here is some sample output.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/Dining$ python3 Dining.py 
welcome to the tip calculator, hope you had a good time
how much was your bill
100
how much would you like to tip?
 No tip, 10% , 15%, 20%
No tip
Thank you for dining.
```

Give that a try.